# Can the empty set be defined as a contradiction in logic?

Tags: logic, set-theory, modal-logic

Can the empty set be defined as something like this in logic?
$$
\square\left(\exists x\mid E(x)\iff \exists x: \neg x=x\right)
$$
Also, how should the empty set be defined in logic? Thanks and simultaneously sorry for my amateurish question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is □ ?  And what is E ?

Comment: Box means necessary and E here would just mean the word empty.

Comment: More or less... given some existential axiom, like Infinity, and Separation, we can use it to carve out from the existing set the empty one using the formula $x \ne x$.

Comment: The null set is not defined as a contradiction. Being an element of the null set is what  is defined in terms of a contradiction. This is why the null set is the set with no elements. By the axiom of extentionality, all sets whose elements are defined via contradiction are equivalent- so even though there are many different possible definitions- there is only one "Empty Set/Null Set", as they are all equivalent.

Comment: Rereading your question, I realized you may be asking if there is a way to capture the essence of the empty set, in a theory that doesn't have the ∈ symbol as part of its syntax. I would say that no, there isnt a way to do so, in standard formal logic. The important features of the empty set, are with respect to the ∈-relation.

Comment: The empty set is a set; contradictions are sentences; these are teo different kinds of things. However, the empty set can be defined using any contradiction $S$: it’s the set of all $x$ such that $S$. It doesn’t matter whether $x$ occurs at all in $S$. Strictly speaking, in ZF we form sets in this way using the axiom of comprehension, which lets us form the (sub)set of all $x$ in some existing set such that $S$. Other ZF axioms guarantee that some sets exist! Let $A$ be one of them. Then $\emptyset = \{x\in A: S\}$.

Answer (score 3):

The null set can be defined using a contradiction, but not explicitly as a contradiction. That is, if we have that a set $A$ already exists, then we can use the Axiom of Separation to get the subset of $A$ that contains exactly those members of $x\in A$ such that $x\not=x$. Since nothing fits this requirement, it follows that the subset of $A$ in question is empty. Then, you can use the Axiom of Extensionality to prove its uniqueness.

Comment: Axiom of "substitution"? Maybe you meant "comprehension"?

Comment: Break this down for me: are you deriving a contradiction, meaning a contradiction is in the definition? What about the first definition I have above? Does that count? Can that count as using a contradiction in the definition of an empty set or just explicitly defining it as a contradiction?

Comment: @Brizim all you’re doing is using the axioms I mentioned to show that for a given set $A$ there is a unique subset of $A$ that has exactly members $x$ such that $x \not = x$. The example you gave is just a logical expression that is false in reflexive Kripke frames, whereas the existence and uniqueness of the null set is true in important set theories.

Comment: @Brizim you’re not going to be able to define the null set without the membership relation.

Comment: I appreciate your response. Here's my problem: "for a given set A there is a unique subset of A that has exactly members x such that x does not equal x" sounds a lot like ∀x(Sx→∃x(¬x=x)) when S just means is a set, but necessarily, ¬∃x(¬x=x), which also means no set exists. It also sounds a lot like the null set implies a contradiction. I honestly am a complete amateur so don't know what Kripke frames are, but will have to read up on it.

Comment: @Brizim the existence of the null set is stated as $\exists x \forall y \: y \not \in x$, which is equivalent to $\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y \not =y)$.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful. You're certain on the equivalency?

Comment: @Brizim yes it’s correct.

Answer (score 3):

In axiomatic set theory we typically just stipulate the *existence* of an empty set by something like $\exists x \forall y \ y \not \in x$.  (or, provide some set of axioms from which this statement can be derived).  So the formula $\forall y \ y \not \in x$ can be used as a formula ('predicate') to say that $x$ is empty.  If you insist on using a predicate symbol $E$ where you want to use $E(x)$ to say that set $x$ is empty, you can do something like $$\forall x (E(x) \leftrightarrow \forall y \ y \not \in x)$$

Note that an empty set is of course not the same as a contradiction ... but I am guessing you are thinking something along the lines of: if an empty set would contain something, we would obtain a contradiction ... you could capture that idea by: $$\forall x (E(x) \leftrightarrow \forall y (y \in x \to \bot))$$

Answer (score 2):

While a contradiction is obtained as an intermediate result in a proof of the existence of an empty set (see line 10 below), its existence should not be thought of as a contradiction in itself.

Further to other answers here, given the existence of any set, it is also possible to prove the the existence of an empty set *without* the use of the equality relation and reflexivity. (Saves 4 lines.) Using a form of natural deduction, we have the following text version of a proof with side scroll bar:

```
Let x be any set.

1   Set(x)
    Premise

Apply Subset Axiom

2   EXIST(a):[Set(a) & ALL(b):[b in a <=> b in x & ~b in x]]
    Subset, 1

3   Set(y) & ALL(b):[b in y <=> b in x & ~b in x]
    E Spec, 2

4   Set(y)
    Split, 3

5   ALL(b):[b in y <=> b in x & ~b in x]
    Split, 3

    Suppose...

    6   z in y
        Premise

    7   z in y <=> z in x & ~z in x
        U Spec, 5

    8   [z in y => z in x & ~z in x] & [z in x & ~z in x => z in y]
        Iff-And, 7

    9   z in y => z in x & ~z in x
        Split, 8

    Obtain the contradiction... 

    10  z in x & ~z in x
        Detach, 9, 6

11  ~EXIST(c):c in y
    Conclusion, 6

12  Set(y) & ~EXIST(c):c in y
    Join, 4, 11

As Required:

13  ALL(a):[Set(a) => EXIST(b):[Set(b) & ~EXIST(c):c in b]]
    Conclusion, 1
```

HTML version available.

Answer (score 0):

not necessarily. Technically it could be the case that:
$\exists$ x (Ex $\land$ x = x),[which is actually quite intuitive, it seems exaggerated to deny that the set of all prime even numbers is identical to itself, even if it is obviously empty], or that an empty set doesnt entail or is equivalent to any other contradiction. One could get a contradiction to entail an empty set, such as claiming that, given a set A in which u are an element of it if and only if u r a true contradiction, that set A will be empty, as in:

($\exists$ A(x $\in$ A $\iff$ Dx) $\to$ $\exists$ A(A = {$\emptyset$})}, in which "Dx" means "x is a Dialetheia", and Dialetheia is the term for a true contradiction. But im not sure if we could actually define an empty set as a contradiction. It generally can be used to denote contradictions, such as the set of all pieces of matter who dont occupy space or the set of all feline humans, but the notion of an empty set is not itself defined as a contradiction. Really it just means a set which has no elements, or:

$\forall$ x(Ex $\iff$ ($\forall$ y(y $\notin$ x))).

Surely all sets with contradictory properties will be empty sets, but it is not necessarily (as a first impression) the case that there is no set which lacks contradictory properties and is an empty set, which would be necessary if an empty set definitionally (and thus necessarily) has atleast one contradictory property.